# How to detect recoverable error from JMSException for IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I receive JMSException from `producer.send(message)` JMS API for IBM MQ. The question is how I can detect that I got recoverable exception (exception connected to recoverable error/problem)?

I wonder if I can use: `ex.getErrorCode()`.
If yes, where I can fine recoverable error codes?

I found:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqsao.doc/fm12040_1.htm
and
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q080450_.htm

but there is no clear information which error can be recoverable.

Comment: You should look at reconnect, if you turn this on the IBM MQ Classes for JMS will automatically handle the reconnect in situations where it is supported.  The KC has more details on this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working always - see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032520_.htm

"Automatic client reconnection is only available to stand-alone IBM MQ classes for JMS applications. The use of automatic client reconnection within Java™ Platform, Enterprise Edition application servers is not supported.", but thanks for answer.